# JavaScript 2d array causing "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined

i'm attempting to read from a global 2d array in javascript and it gives me "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined".

Here's how I'm defining my array:

```
var cell = {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true}

var cells = new Array(10);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Initiate 2d cells array.
{
  cells[i] = new Array(cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell);
}
```

I'm then accessing it later like this:

```
if(x != 0) //Left
{
    if(cells[x-1][y].visited == false)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

x and y are never out of bounds of the defined array so I'm not sure why this is occuring.

Thanks!

Comment: What are x and y? How are they created and modified?

Comment: It's up to you to make sure that x-1 and y can only be numbers from 0-9.

Comment: In what scopes do you create and use your array? Because with `var` it won't be global.

Comment: How do I make it global then?

Comment: remove `var` keyword before variable name

Comment: x and y are declared as var x = 0; etc. earlier in the code. x and y are only increased if they are < 10 and only decreased if > 0

Comment: try to change `var cells = new Array(10);` to `cells = new Array(10);`

Comment: Thanks!! I think it was the fact that it wasn't a global variable. All set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create global variable you need create it in global scope or just omit `var` keyword when declaring it.
As I see, you used `var` keyword, so your variable could be global only if it's created in global scope.

Just use `cells = new Array(10);` instead of `var cells = new Array(10);`.

Btw. It is better to avoid global variables if it is possible.

### Suggestion

Additionally I'd like to suggest you creating your two-dimensional array this way.
You pass your `cell` variable by reference. So changing it in one place will change it everywhere.

```
cells = new Array(10).fill().map(function(cell) {
    return new Array(10).fill().map(function() {
        return {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true};
    })
});
```

Comment: Please don't recommend such an horrible practice. Declare it with `var` but in global scope. Or better, wrap all code inside an IIFE.

Comment: I've suggested fix and explained the reason why it is not working. Also I've said that it's better to avoid global variables if possible.